# Auto-Generate Method Code in Objective-C Subclasses

Tags: objective-c, ios5

You know how when you make a subclass of `UITableViewController` the `.m` file is automatically populated with the view life cycle methods?

Is there a way to do the same to a custom class? I would like to somehow document a requirement of a subclass to set a property.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you want can actually be done as what you are referring to is a template of iOS. auto generating methods of your own doesn't seem feasible to me. Though you can create your own templates like this.. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/05/19/custom-xcode-template-for-iphone-development/ and http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-design-your-own-xcode-project-templates.ars